# Nginx & Django & Gunicorn - Redirecting subdomain to app

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, subdomain, django, gunicorn

I did an extensive search on the topic but nothing could help me.

I am currently building a Django site, and using Nginx to reverse proxy to Gunicorn.

I am trying to separate my apps into subdomains. (blog.example.com, admin.example.com, user.example.com etc.)

I took care of the DNS records and they are working accordingly since my initial project was using only Nginx.

I can access the apps by navigating to the "subfolder" example.com/blog.

The config looks like this:

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn socket for example.com

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/example.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon for example.com
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=example
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/example/project
ExecStart=/home/sammy/project/projectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/example:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/example/project;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

I did add another serverblock for blog.example.com and added /blog on the proxy_pass line: `proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock/blog;` hoping it will redirect to the app folder.

I am new to the socket method and do I don't know how to achieve the redirect.

I am aware that Nginx should handle the redirect and everything, but don't know to proceed further.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could have one gunicorn service per app:

**/etc/systemd/system/blog.example.com.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon for blog.example.com
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=example
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/example/project/blog
ExecStart=/home/sammy/project/projectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/blog.example.com.sock \
          project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/etc/systemd/system/admin.example.com.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon for admin.example.com
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=example
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/example/project/admin
ExecStart=/home/sammy/project/projectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/admin.example.com.sock \
          project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then point nginx to the respective `.sock` files:

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/blog.example.com**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blog.example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/example/project;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/blog.example.com.sock;
    }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/admin.example.com**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name admin.example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/example/project;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/admin.example.com.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input.

Unfortunately this results in a 502 - Bad gateway error.
It is also something I tried before.

Comment: Make sure the `.sock` files are existing and accessible by nginx. The error log of nginx should contain a clue too.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **separate service and socket files** for every app and use **explicit hosts instead of unix sockets**.

Change the terms like `unix:/run/blog` with something like `127.0.0.1:8000` in your **socket** and **service** files. `WorkingDirectory` parameter should be same in all service files, it should point the directory contains `manage.py`. Finally you should set `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/;` in your **nginx** config.

**/etc/systemd/system/blog.example.com.socket**

```
Unit]
Description=Gunicorn socket for blog.example.comg

[Socket]
ListenStream=8000

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

**/etc/systemd/system/blog.example.com.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon for blog.example.com
Requires=blog.example.com.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=example
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/example/project/blog
ExecStart=/home/sammy/project/projectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 \
          project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/blog-example:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blog.example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/example/project;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000/blog/;
    }
}
```